# How to make a REST call when specific events occur in Outlook 365 Using a VSTO Add-In

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make an Outlook 365 add-in that does the following:

When an email is flagged for follow up (Today, Tomorrow, This Week, etc):

- A rest API call is made to a server, eg: http://localhost:8080/email/flagged, with post data that includes the email from, subject, body, and flag name (today, tomorrow, etc).  If each email has a unique id of some sort, sending that value as well.

When an email is UN-flagged for follow up:

- A rest API call is made to a server, eg: http://localhost:8080/email/unflagged/{uniqueEmailId} , if there is a unique id assigned to each email available for use,  otherwise post data that contains the from and subject values from the email.

I am looking at using VSTO but I have never used it or any other of the MS Office add-in tools.

I have too many questions, for starters:

1. Can an outlook add-in make HTTP REST calls to an outside web API service?
2. Are there exposed events in the ThisAddIn object related to when an email is flagged/unflagged?

As far as code,  I have a blank slate (VB shown but will accept C# suggestions too):

```
Dim WithEvents currentExplorer As Outlook.Explorer = Nothing

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, _
     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

     'register a handler for the events I am interested in (need help here)

End Sub

Private Sub MyEventHandler(someEventObject)
   'Get basic data (need help here too), eg:
   Dim eventName = someEventObject.EventType
   Dim EmailUniqueId = someEventObject.Uid
   Dim EmailFrom = someEventObject.FromEmailAddress
   Dim Subject =  someEventObject.Subject

   'Send an HTTP REST call (I know how to do that) 
End Sub
```

FYI - I am a web developer so I naturally want to gravitate to a solution that would send an HTTP REST API call for this.  However, if that is not possible I am open to other ideas for getting these event details out of Outlook,  even going so low as to create a file that contains the basic event/email information in a folder that could be parsed by a scheduled job.  This project is just something I am making for myself to use for work so it doesn't have to be elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, anything a regular Windows app can do, your VSTO addin can do just as easily.

To make an HTTP request, take a look at the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) class

To monitor events on a particular folder use [Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) events. The item the that caused the event will be passed to your event handler. Since you can have different types of items in the same folder (e.g. [ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.reportitem?view=sqlserver-2016) and [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) objects), the parameter is declared as a generic `object` and you will need to explicitly interrogate the object type using the `as` or `is` operators.

To open the folder you are interested in, you can use, for example, `Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`.

Comment: Glad to know I can make the REST calls, that takes care of question #1, thanks!  Any insight into question #2?

Comment: Yes, see paragraphs 3 and 4 of my answer.